# Django Responsive Form using class:'form-control'

Tags: django, forms, responsive-design

I have a from and added a bootstrap class':'form-control' to every field of the form to make them responsive like this :

```
     companyname=forms.CharField( widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'class':'form-control' ,'style': 'width:30%'}) )
```

but when i add form-control class , the label is showd at the upper row of the text box

i dont know what to do to bring the label beside the text box

when it has no class the code below is ok but its not responsive

```
    <div class="panel-body" style="text-align:right ; margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;width:80%;">

    <div style="width:85% ;margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;">
    <form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" >

      {% csrf_token %}
      {{ profile_form.as_p}}

      <input id="savepersonalinfo" type="submit" name="" value="ثبت">
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

and also how can i put the textboxes arranged exactly in same column ?

[image]

in the picutre iust companyname has form-control class and is responsive and other fields are not

Comment: Can you paste your css?

Comment: it has nothing to do with form-control class . form-control is a bootstrap class

Comment: Any other ways to make my form responsive ?